# Changes in resource handler

Tags: windows-10, download, process, storage, resource-monitor

I'm trying to find out where an application on Windows 10 stores some files when I download them.

I tried using the *resource monitor* tool (under the CPU tab), which links every selected *process* with some *associated handles*.

The problem is that this process handles a lot of files, and I can't find a way to discover the new handled files whenever I start the download.

Any suggestions? (no probs if some c++ is required)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), then, add the following Filter: **Category** Is **Write** then **Include**.
This is useful in your case because it will only show "Write" events ("Read" events will be hidden).

[image: Process Monitor Filter dialog with Category Is Write rule created]

If you know the Process Name, you can add a filter with the process name too, or drag-drop the bull's eye icon afterwards on the target window (if any).

[image: bullseye icon]

Ensure that only File System activity is enabled in the toolbar to hide registry, network, process events:
[image: File system activity]

Don't forget to stop the capture with the magnifying glass icon (or File -> Capture Events) when your app finished the operation to avoid logging irrelevant events.

Comment: Wow... that's awesome. Thank you!